# Loop through SAS variables and create data sets

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS data set t3. I want to run a data step inside a loop through a set of variables to create additional sets based on the variable value = 1, and rank two variables bal and otheramt in each subset, and then merge the ranks for each subset onto the original data set. Each rank column needs to be dynamically named so I know what subset is getting ranked. I know how to do proc rank and macros basically but do not know how to do this in the most dynamic way inside of a macro. Can you assist?

| ID | bal | otheramt | firstvar | secondvar | lastvar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 444 | 581 | 100 | 1 |  | 1 |
| 555 | 255 | 200 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 666 | 255 | 300 | -------------- | 1 | -------------- |

```
%macro dog();

data new;
set t3;
ARRAY Indicators(5) FirstVar--LastVar;

/*create data set for each of the subsets if firstvar = 1, secondvar = 1 ... lastvar = 1 */

/*for each new data set, rank by bal and otheramt*/
/*name the new rank columns [FirstVar]BalRank, [FirstVar]OtherAmtRank; */

/*merge the new ranks onto the original data set by ID*/
%mend;

%dog()
```

The Proc rank section would be something like this, but I would need the rank columns to have information about what subset I am ranking.

```
proc rank data=subset1 out=subset1ranked;
   var bal otheramt;
   ranks bal_rank otheramt_rank;
run;
```

Comment: Can you show the full code for two variables, without any macro logic and the end result?

Comment: see edits above. Does this help? I provided some sample data above.

Comment: Are you just asking whether you can use a BY statement with PROC RANK?

Comment: No, I need to know how to dynamically name the new rank variables depending on the subset I am ranking. So if there is a variable named KittyIndicator, I will need two  new variables with the rank of bal and otheramt, like KittyBalrank and Kittyotheramtrank.

Comment: Your example doesn't show the subset issue at all so it's still not a full example IMO. I don't think the answers below reflect the subset issue either. I think BY is the right answer.

Comment: Here's a a macro that may be useful, if you're not using groups= remove that from the macro and macro call.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/7cffd06ebc3bc9c78b4f6a5b4538b053

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using macro, use data transformation and reshaping that allows simpler steps to be written.

Example:

Rows are split into multiple rows based on flag so group processing in RANK can occur.  Two transposes are required to reshape the results back a single row per id.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230216);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    foo = rand('integer', 50,150);
    bar = rand('integer', 100,200);
    flag1 = rand('integer', 0, 1);
    flag2 = rand('integer', 0, 1);
    flag3 = rand('integer', 0, 1);
    output;
  end;
run;

data step1;
  set have;

  /* important: the group value becomes part of the variable name later */

  if flag1 then do; group='flag1_'; output; end;
  if flag2 then do; group='flag2_'; output; end;
  if flag3 then do; group='flag3_'; output; end;

  drop flag:;
run;

proc sort data=step1;
  by group;
run;

proc rank data=step1 out=step2;
  by group;
  var foo bar;
  ranks foo_rank bar_rank;
run;

proc sort data=step2;
  by id group;
run;

* pivot (reshape) so there is one row per ranked var;
proc transpose data=step2 out=step3(drop=_label_);
  by id foo bar group;
  var foo_rank bar_rank;
run;

* pivot again so there is one row per id;
proc transpose data=step3 out=step4(drop=_name_);
  by id;
  var col1;
  id group _name_;
run;

* merge so those 0 0 0 flag rows remain intact;
data want;
  merge have step4;
  by id;
run;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have much sample data, I created test data from `sashelp.class` with some indicator variables like yours.

```
data have;
set sashelp.class;
firstvar=round(rand('uniform',1));
secondvar=round(rand('uniform',1));
thirdvar=round(rand('uniform',1));
drop sex weight;
run;
```

Partial output:

```
Name    Age Height  firstvar    secondvar   thirdvar
Alfred  14  69      1           0           1
Alice   13  56.5    0           1           1
Barbara 13  65.3    1           0           0
Carol   14  62.8    0           0           0
```

To dynamically rank data based on indicator variables, I created a macro that accepts a list of indicators and rank variables. The 2 lists help to create the specific variable names you requested. Here's the macro call:

```
%rank(indicators=firstvar secondvar thirdvar,
        rank_vars=age height);
```

Here's part of the final output. Notice the indicators in the sample output above coincide with the ranks in this output. Also note that Carol is not in the output because she had no indicators set to 1.

```
Name    Age Height  firstvar_age_rank   firstvar_height_rank    secondvar_age_rank  secondvar_height_rank   thirdvar_age_rank   thirdvar_height_rank
Alfred  14  69      8                   11                      .                   .                       6.5                 10
Alice   13  56.5    .                   .                       3.5                 2                       4.5                 2
Barbara 13  65.3    6.5                 8                       .                   .                       .                   .
Henry   14  63.5    .                   .                       5.5                 5                       .                   .
```

The full macro is listed below. It has 3 parts.

- Create a temp data set with a `group` variable that contains the number of the indicator variable based on the order of the variable in the list. Whenever an indicator = 1 the obs is output. If an obs has all 3 indicators set to 1 then it will be output 3 times with the `group` variable set to the number of each indicator variable. This step is important because `proc rank` will rank groups independently.
- Generate the rankings on the temp data set. Each group will be ranked independently of the other groups and can be done in one step.
- Construct the final data set by essentially transposing the ranked data into columns.

```
%macro rank(indicators=, rank_vars=);

%let cnt_ind = %sysfunc(countw(&indicators));
%let cnt_vars = %sysfunc(countw(&rank_vars));

data temp;
set have;
array indicators(*) &indicators;
 
do i = 1 to dim(indicators);
    if indicators(i) = 1 then do;
        group = i;  * create a group based on order of indicators;
        output;  * an obs can be output multiple times;
    end;
end;
drop i &indicators;
run;
 
proc sort data=temp;
by group;
run;
 

* Generate rankings by group;
proc rank data=temp out=ranks;
by group;
var &rank_vars;
ranks 
    %let vars = ;
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt_vars;
        %let var = %scan(&rank_vars, &i);
        %let vars = &vars &var._rank;
    %end;
    &vars;
run;

proc sort data=ranks;
by name group;
run; 


* Contruct final data set by transposing the ranks into columns;
data want;
set ranks;
by name;

* retain statement to declare new variables and retain values;
retain
    %let vars = ;
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt_ind;
        %let ivar = %scan(&indicators, &i);
        %do j = 1 %to &cnt_vars;
            %let jvar = %scan(&rank_vars, &j);
            %let vars = &vars &ivar._&jvar._rank;
        %end;
    %end;
    &vars;


if first.name then call missing (of &vars);

* option 1: build series of IF statements;
%let vars = ;
%do i = 1 %to &cnt_ind;
    %let ivar = %scan(&indicators, &i);
    %str(if group = &i then do;)

    %do j = 1 %to &cnt_vars;
        %let jvar = %scan(&rank_vars, &j);
        %let newvar = &ivar._&jvar._rank;
        %str(&newvar = &jvar._rank;)
    %end;
    %str(end;)
%end;

if last.name then output;
drop group 
    %let vars = ;
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt_vars;
        %let var = %scan(&rank_vars, &i);
        %let vars = &vars &var._rank;
    %end;
    &vars;

run;

%mend;
```

When constructing the final data set and transposing the rank variables, there are a couple of options. The first option shown above is to dynamically build a series of `if` statements. Here is what the code generates:

```
MPRINT(RANK):   * option 1: build series of IF statements;
MPRINT(RANK):   if group = 1 then do;
MPRINT(RANK):   firstvar_age_rank = age_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   firstvar_height_rank = height_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   end;
MPRINT(RANK):   if group = 2 then do;
MPRINT(RANK):   secondvar_age_rank = age_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   secondvar_height_rank = height_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   end;
MPRINT(RANK):   if group = 3 then do;
MPRINT(RANK):   thirdvar_age_rank = age_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   thirdvar_height_rank = height_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   end;
```

The 2nd option is to use an array and mathematically calculate the index into the array by the group number and variable number. Here is the snippet of macro code to replace the `if` series code:

```
* option 2: create arrays and calculate index into array 
* by group number and variable number;
array ranks(*) &vars;
array rankvars(*) 
    %let vars = ;
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt_vars;
        %let var = %scan(&rank_vars, &i);
        %let vars = &vars &var._rank;
    %end;
    &vars;

%str(idx = dim(rankvars) * (group - 1);)
%str(do i = 1 to dim(rankvars);)
%str(ranks(idx + i) = rankvars(i);)
%str(end;)
```

Here is the generated code:

```
MPRINT(RANK):   * option 2: create arrays and calculate index into array * by group number and variable number;
MPRINT(RANK):   array ranks(*) firstvar_age_rank firstvar_height_rank secondvar_age_rank secondvar_height_rank thirdvar_age_rank 
thirdvar_height_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   array rankvars(*) age_rank height_rank;
MPRINT(RANK):   idx = dim(rankvars) * (group - 1);
MPRINT(RANK):   do i = 1 to dim(rankvars);
MPRINT(RANK):   ranks(idx + i) = rankvars(i);
MPRINT(RANK):   end;
```

It takes a minute to understand the array option, but once you do, it is preferable over generating `if` statments. As the number of variables increases, the code generated by the array option is the same and operates more efficiently.